# Every crash shown as android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable, Not the correct exception is shown in play store

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I cannot pinpoint to what caused the crash from the crash log inside Playstore console all it shows is android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable. Some times the place is also shown but the orginal exception that gets thrown is not shown . Its a cross platform xamarin forms application. In my case log looks like

```
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.PlatformRenderer.OnLayout (System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x00024] in <63e7c9910ab446ac9b78b1ac3ac3e5bb>:0
at Android.Views.ViewGroup.n_OnLayout_ZIIII (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.Boolean changed, System.Int32 l, System.Int32 t, System.Int32 r, System.Int32 b) [0x00008] in <eaa205f580954a64824b74a79fa87c62>:0
at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.27(intptr,intptr,bool,int,int,int,int)
  at crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.PlatformRenderer.n_onLayout (Native Method)
  at crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.PlatformRenderer.onLayout (PlatformRenderer.java:63)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:24475)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:7383)
  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout (RelativeLayout.java:1103)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:24475)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:7383)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:332)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:270)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:24475)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:7383)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:332)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:270)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:24475)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:7383)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:332)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:270)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:24475)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:7383)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame (LinearLayout.java:1829)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical (LinearLayout.java:1673)
  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout (LinearLayout.java:1582)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:24475)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:7383)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren (FrameLayout.java:332)
  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout (FrameLayout.java:270)
  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout (DecorView.java:1225)
  at android.view.View.layout (View.java:24475)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.layout (ViewGroup.java:7383)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout (ViewRootImpl.java:4260)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:2618)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:9971)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:1010)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:809)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:744)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:995)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:246)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8512)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:602)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

Comment: Just based on the log, the cause of the problem cannot be found. So could you provide a sample to reproduce this issue.

Comment: @KyleWang-MSFT I don't know how that issue occur

Comment: Any steps could you provide?